# INSTALL_BASE=~/perl5 -- NOT OK - While installing Perl Module

Tags: perl, module

I am trying to install one of the Perl module in my local system (Windows 7). But its failing to install the module

Here is what its displaying

```
C:\Windows\system32>perl -MCPAN -e "install Net::SFTP"
Reading 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 26 May 2019 05:17:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Net::SFTP'
Checksum for C:\Users\AppData\Local\.cpan\sources\authors\id\L\LK\LKINLE
Y\Net-SFTP-0.12.tar.gz ok
Configuring L/LK/LKINLEY/Net-SFTP-0.12.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Math::Int64 0.54 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Net::SSH::Perl 2.12 not found.
The getpwuid function is unimplemented at C:/Perl64/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm li
ne 1064.
Warning: No success on command[C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=~
/perl5]
  LKINLEY/Net-SFTP-0.12.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=~/perl5 -- NOT OK
```

It was working fine before and I have installed couple of modules, don't know what happens suddenly.

Please help me to resolve this. Do I need to make any modifications in config?

Comment: `Warning: prerequisite Math::Int64 0.54 not found.`. Maybe try to install the prerequisites first?

Comment: Are you sure it worked with `INSTALL_BASE=~/perl5`? It seems the resolution of `~` is implemented by `getpwuid` which doesn't exist on MSWin.

Comment: @HåkonHægland -  I tried installing Math::Int64 first. And that also gives same error.

Comment: @choroba - What does this INSTALL_BASE means? Do you think I need to make correction over here?

Comment: @vinodk89 *"..gives same error"* what error is that?

Comment: @HåkonHægland - Here is the error message `The getpwuid function is unimplemented at C:/Perl64/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm li
ne 1064. Warning: No success on command[C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=~
/perl5]
  SALVA/Math-Int64-0.54.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=~/perl5 -- NOT OK`

Comment: I am not familiar with Windows, but is it possible to set `INSTALL_BASE` before you install? Like `INSTALL_BASE=C:\path\to\perl5 perl -MCPAN -e "install Net::SFTP"` ? (This to avoid having the tilde `~` in INSTALL_BASE)

Comment: @HåkonHægland - Even I am not sure. But how I can forcefully install the module. using -f doesn't work!!

Comment: @vinodk89 I tried now on cygwin on Windows 10, and it installed `Net::SFTP` fine. I used the `local::lib` option with `cpan` and I did not set `INSTALL_BASE`

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Re "*Maybe try to install the prerequisites first?*", Not the issue. `cpan` will handle the prereqs

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, If you used local::lib, you *did* set `INSTALL_BASE`

Answer (score 1):

You're telling Perl to into `~/perl5`. That's not a Windows path, and ExtUtils::MakeMaker is using a unix-specific function (`getpwuid`) to expand it. Your problem should go away if you use a Windows path.

That said, if you have access to write to `C:\Perl64\...`, I suggest that you install modules to the default directory by removing `INSTALL_BASE=~/perl5`.

If you don't have access to write to `C:\Perl64\...`, I suggest that you install Perl itself in a directly to which you do have access to write, and then I'd install modules to the default directory by removing `INSTALL_BASE=~/perl5`.

Since you didn't actually specify `INSTALL_BASE=~/perl5` on the command line, you are specifying it through the environment (`PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT`),  or in `cpan`'s configuration (`o conf` from within `cpan`).

Comment: So what windows path I should use? Do you mean that I should make changes in ../MyConfig.pm file?

Comment: Re "*So what windows path I should use?*", As I said, you shouldn't use `INSTALL_BASE` at all.

Comment: Re "*Do you mean that I should make changes in ../MyConfig.pm file?*", No, I meant what I said. You'll need to change the environment or use `cpan`'s `o conf` command. You should never edit `cpan`'s config file directly.

Comment: Is there any way that I can revert back my changes or I can make a default settings? I'm not remembering where I made changes to INSTALL_BASE.

Comment: Re "*Is there any way that I can revert back my changes or I can make a default settings?*", Yes. In fact, that's what I recommend you do.

Comment: Re "*I'm not remembering where I made changes to INSTALL_BASE.*", Then check. I told you the two places it can be.

Comment: I have added proper lib path to 'makepl_arg' in MyConfig.pm and its working now.
But new error is occaring 'C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK'.
Can someone please tell me what should be the value for 'make' and 'make_arg' in MyConfig.pm ?

Comment: Fine, don't follow my advice. So you're having problems, you say.

Comment: There are the things I have added to 'makepl_arg'
0 [PREFIX=~/lib/perl5]
1 [LIB=~/lib/perl5/lib]

Comment: Neither of those makes sense for a Windows build of Perl. Clear it with `o conf makepl_arg ''`. Might need to do the same to `mbuildpl_arg`

Comment: Done but no luck. Still this error is coming -  C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK

Comment: That message simply indicates an error occurred earlier

Comment: Yep. And I could see this path is mentioned in for `make               [C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   [UNINST=1]
    make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/make]
`. So doubting that I am missing something over here?

Comment: Still can't help unless you show the relevant error message

Comment: Here it is `dmake.exe:  Error executing '\bin\bash': No such file or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'blib\lib\Net\.exists'
  LKINLEY/Net-SFTP-0.12.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
`

Comment: How did you mess up your system so bad? It's like you copied files from a unix system?!!?

Comment: Try running `o conf init` from within `cpan`. Press Enter when asked "Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically?". THIS WILL CLOBBER YOUR `cpan` SETTINGS (but surely you made a backup of them before you started editing them earlier...)